# problem in flutter web which is => stagehand does not support dart 2.1.0

Tags: flutter-web

I'm just started to use flutter for web development
and after upgrading flutter and running "pub global activate stagehand"

this message shows up when I try creating a flutter web project

(" Unable to execute Stagehand. Stagehand exited with code 65. stagehand 3.3.0 doesn't support Dart 2.1.0. ")

despite my dart-sdk version is 2.3.0

how can I fix this ??

Answer (score 2):

I installed the new version of flutter "flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable" and it worked